# How do I run this Python 2.7 script over multiple files in the same directory

Tags: python

This script currently grabs specific types of IP addresses out of a file, formats them into csv.

How do I change this to get it to look through all files in its directory (same dir as script) and create a new output file. This is my first week on python so please be as simple as possible.

```
  #!usr/bin/python

    # Extract IP address from file 

    #import modules
    import re

    # Open Source File
    infile = open('stix1.xml', 'r')
    # Open output file
    outfile = open('ExtractedIPs.csv', 'w') 
    # Create a list
    BadIPs = []

    #search each line in doc
    for line in infile:
        # ignore empty lines
        if line.isspace(): continue

        # find IP that are Indicator Titles
        IP = (re.findall(r"(?:<indicator:Title>IP:) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", line))
        # Only take finds
        if not IP: continue
        # Add each found IP to the BadIP list
        BadIPs.append(IP)

    #tidy up for CSV format
    data = str(BadIPs)
    data = data.replace('[', '')
    data = data.replace(']', '')
    data = data.replace("'", "")
    # Write IPs to a file        
    outfile.write(data)

    infile.close
    outfile.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you want to add all outputs to the same file this would be the script:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import glob   
import re

for infileName in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    # Open Source File
    infile = open(infileName, 'r')
    # Append to file
    outfile = open('ExtractedIPs.csv', 'a') 
    # Create a list
    BadIPs = []

    #search each line in doc
    for line in infile:
        # ignore empty lines
        if line.isspace(): continue

        # find IP that are Indicator Titles
        IP = (re.findall(r"(?:<indicator:Title>IP:) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", line))
        # Only take finds
        if not IP: continue
        # Add each found IP to the BadIP list
        BadIPs.append(IP)

    #tidy up for CSV format
    data = str(BadIPs)
    data = data.replace('[', '')
    data = data.replace(']', '')
    data = data.replace("'", "")
    # Write IPs to a file        
    outfile.write(data)

    infile.close
    outfile.close
```

Answer (score 2):

I thinks you want to have a look at glob.glob: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

This will return a list of files matching a given pattern.

then you can do something like
    import re, glob

```
def do_something_with(f):
   # Open Source File
   infile = open(f, 'r')
   # Open output file
   outfile = open('ExtractedIPs.csv', 'wa')  ## ADDED a to append
   # Create a list
   BadIPs = []

   ### rest of you code
   .
   .
   outfile.write(data)

   infile.close
   outfile.close

for f in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    do_something_with(f)
```

Comment: where would i be adding this? in your example would f go in infile =open(f)?

Comment: @DnkApollo - You would want to wrap this around everything you have currently written. Then, instead of `infile = open('stix1.xml', 'r')`, you would have `infile = open(f, 'r')`. Your `outfile` line should be outside of the `glob` loop - that way it's only opened once and everything from every xml gets added to it (unless you want multiple csv files generated?)

Answer (score 1):

You could get a list of all XML files like this.

```
filenames = [nm for nm in os.listdir() if nm.endswith('.xml')]
```

And then you iterate over all the files.

```
for fn in filenames:
    with open(fn) as infile:
        for ln in infile:
            # do your thing
```

The `with`-statement makes sure that the file is closed after you're done with it.

Comment: `glob` is superior to `listdir`, I think... certainly it ends up being more concise. But +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

1. `import sys`
2. Make a function out of your current code, for examle `def extract(filename)`.
3. Call the script with all filenames: `python myscript.py file1 file2 file3`
4. Inside your script, loop over the filenames `for filename in sys.argv[1:]:`.
5. Call the function inside the loop: `extract(filename)`.

Comment: this sounds good, the problem is there will be thousands of small files

Comment: The shell can do this for you: `python myscript.py filepattern*`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to do this, and also to go into subdirectories as well.  You need to import os and os.path, then can use a function like this:

```
def recursive_glob(rootdir='.', suffix=()):
    """ recursively traverses full path from route, returns
        paths and file names for files with suffix in tuple """
    pathlist = []
    filelist = []
    for looproot,dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(suffix):
                pathlist.append(os.path.join(looproot, filename))
                filelist.append(filename)
    return pathlist, filelist
```

You pass the function the top level directory you want to start from and the suffix for the file type you are looking for. This was written and tested for Windows,  but I believe it will work on other OS's as well, as long as you've got file extensions to work from.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `os.listdir()` if all files in your current folder are relevant. If not, say all the `.xml` files, then use `glob.glob("*.xml")`. But the overall program can be improved, roughly as follows.

```
#import modules
import re

pat = re.compile(reg) # reg is your regex
with open("out.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for f in os.listdir(): # or glob.glob("*.xml")
        with open(f) as fr:
            lines = (line for line in fr if line.isspace())
            # genex for all ip in that file
            ips = (ip for line in lines for ip in pat.findall(line))
            writer.writerow(ips)
```

You probably have to change it to suit to exact needs. But the idea is in this version there are a lot less side effects, lot less memory consumption and `close` is managed by the context manager. Please comment if doesn't work.